# Secret key when use Facebook SDK for ANdroid

Tags: android, facebook, key

This code works fine:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("to", String.valueOf());
mFacebook.dialog(, "feed", params, );
```

/*code from facebook developer site*/

This code doesn't work because of wrong app secret key:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
 parameters.putString("method", "auth.expireSession", new Listener());
 String response = request(parameters);
```

/*code from facebook developer site*/

In both cases I provide app ID.
I don't see difference using dialog and request. How dialog works fine /without providing secret app key/ and request fails because of this key?

---

In short:
Without 'Android Key Hash' my request fails. It is expected behaviour.
Without 'Android Key Hash' my dialog is sending posts to Facebook without any problem.
It's showing Facebook send message form, but still is possible to send.

Comment: Both samples were tried in the same application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible answer for now is: sending data using dialog is possible because dialog appear on screen and it is user decision to confirm them or not.